# Как реализовать слайдер с помощью slick.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, можно ли такой слайдер сделать с помощью slick? Как я понял, должен меняться фон у слайдера

Comment: фон должен меняться?

Comment: Да, фон должен меняться

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать подобное легко, нужно блок с контентом абсолютнно позиционированировать относительно всей секции с слайдером.
Примерно как то [так](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/QqjMmJ)

```css
.gallery__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

.info_block {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="info_block">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
  </div>
   <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__item" style=" background-color: pink;"></div>
         <div class="gallery__item" style=" background-color: red;"></div>
         <div class="gallery__item" style=" background-color: green;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```